# how to find duplication by comparing field 1 and field 2 in awk?

Tags: awk

I want to compare field 1 with field 2 and find duplication

For eg: file contains below data

```
51:40-5E:40
51:41-5E:41
51:42-51:40
51:52-5E:52
51:A0-5E:A0
51:A9-5D:B8
51:AA-5E:53
```

In this file `51:40` is found in `$1` and  `$2` so I need this `51:40` to be printed when running the script

Comment: file pasted differently

Comment: 51:40-5E:40
51:41-5E:41

Comment: 51:40-5E:40
51:41-5E:41
51:42-5E:42
51:52-5E:52

Comment: File:
51:40-5E:40
51:41-5E:41
51:42-5E:42
51:52-5E:52
51:A0-51:40

Comment: So what have you done so far?

Answer (score 1):

This awk one-liner might work for you:

```
awk -F- '$1 in a{print $1}{b[$1]}$2 in b{print $2}{a[$2]}' file
```

Answer (score 1):

You want

```
awk '
    BEGIN {FS = "-"}
    {
        field1[$1]++ 
        field2[$2]++
    } 
    END {
        for (item in field1) {
            if (item in field2) {
                print item
            }
        }
    }
' filename
```

as a one-liner:

```
awk -F- '{a[$1];b[$2]} END {for (i in a) if (i in b) print i}' filename
```